# Cloudformation intrinsic function Fn::Sub mapping

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudformation

I don't understand why `Fn::Sub` in this template is not working.
I get the following error:

> Template contains errors.: Template error: One or more Fn::Sub intrinsic functions don't specify expected arguments. Specify a string as first argument, and an optional second argument to specify a mapping of values to replace in the string

```
Resources:
  LambdaSubmitJob:
    Type: 'AWS::Lambda::Function'
    Properties:
      Handler: index.lambda_handler
      Runtime: python2.7
      Timeout: 10
      Code:
        ZipFile: |
          import json
          import boto3
  LambdaJobStatusPoll:
    Type: 'AWS::Lambda::Function'
    Properties:
      Handler: index.lambda_handler
      Runtime: python2.7
      Timeout: 10
      Code:
        ZipFile: |
          import json
          import boto3
  MyStepF:
    Type: 'AWS::StepFunctions::StateMachine'
    Properties:
      DefinitionString: !Sub 
        - |-
          {
            "Comment": "A state machine that submits a Job to AWS Batch and monitors the Job until it completes.",
            "StartAt": "Submit Job",
            "States": {
              "Submit Job": {
                "Type": "Task",
                "Resource": "${Lambda1}",
                "ResultPath": "$.guid",
                "Next": "Wait 30 seconds"
              },
              {
                "Type": "Task",
                "Resource": "${Lambda2}",
                "ResultPath": "$.guid",
                "Next": "Wait 30 seconds"
              }
            }
          }
        - Lambda2: !GetAtt 
            - LambdaSubmitJob
            - Arn
        - Lambda1: !GetAtt 
            - LambdaJobStatusPoll
            - Arn
```

But if I have only one mapping then it works.

```
Resources:
  LambdaSubmitJob:
    Type: 'AWS::Lambda::Function'
    Properties:
      Handler: index.lambda_handler
      Runtime: python2.7
      Timeout: 10
      Code:
        ZipFile: |
          import json
          import boto3
  LambdaJobStatusPoll:
    Type: 'AWS::Lambda::Function'
    Properties:
      Handler: index.lambda_handler
      Runtime: python2.7
      Timeout: 10
      Code:
        ZipFile: |
          import json
          import boto3
  MyStepF:
    Type: 'AWS::StepFunctions::StateMachine'
    Properties:
      DefinitionString: !Sub 
        - |-
          {
            "Comment": "A state machine that submits a Job to AWS Batch and monitors the Job until it completes.",
            "StartAt": "Submit Job",
            "States": {
              "Submit Job": {
                "Type": "Task",
                "Resource": "${Lambda1}",
                "ResultPath": "$.guid",
                "Next": "Wait 30 seconds"
              }
        - Lambda1: !GetAtt 
            - LambdaJobStatusPoll
            - Arn
```

I am using CloudFormation Designer to validate these two examples.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are giving the `Fn::Sub` function 3 arguments:

1. The *String*
2. Mapping for `Lambda2`
3. Mapping for `Lambda1`

Move both Mappings to a single list item and it will work (I also used the "dot-notation" for !GetAtt for simplicity but that's optional).

```
  DefinitionString: !Sub 
    - |-
      {
         [...]
      }
    - Lambda2: !GetAtt LambdaSubmitJob.Arn
      Lambda1: !GetAtt LambdaJobStatusPoll.Arn
```

Hope that helps :)

Comment: Thank you. I am aware that I'm lacking fundamentals.

Comment: @titus It's just YAML, not much to do with CloudFormation. You may find this overview of YAML *lists* and *mappings* useful: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/yaml/yaml_collections_and_structures.htm

Answer (score 0):

If you are writing a bash script within your metadata, options 1 and 2 in my example code are valid but option 3 is not because **"- |"** tells the sub intrinsic function to expect another **"- |"** as shown in option 1, that should provide mapping of values (e.g ***- {A mapping of some sort}***) to replace strings inside ***{blablabla}***. When the second mapping is not found, the error is thrown.

```
Metadata:
  AWS::CloudFormation::Init:
   files:
   ##### use
    '/dir/subdir':
      content: !Sub
        - |
          {blablabla}
        - {A mapping of some sort}
    ###### or 

    '/dir2/subdir2':
      content: !Sub |
          {blablabla}

    ##### But don't mix like so

    '/dir3/subdir3':
      content: !Sub
        - |
          {blablabla}
```